# How do I change the position of an image on an embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot that replies commands with the user's avatar, member id, and date, but the problem is, it's putting the image at the bottom of the embed, and I would like to have it between the embed title and the id/date field. How do I do that?

My code:

```
import datetime

bot = discord.Client()
token = 'haha'

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$test'):
        teste = message.author.mention
        authorId = message.author.id
        tempo = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        avatar = message.author.avatar_url_as(format='jpg', static_format='webp', size=2048)

        embed=discord.Embed(name="title", description=f"\U0001F5BC {teste} **alterou o avatar**", color=message.author.colour)
        embed.set_image(url=avatar)
        embed.add_field(name=f"ID do usuário: {authorId} • {tempo}", value="​")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(token)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general issue with Discord embeds - the layout is somewhat fixed.
You either have fields or you don't.

This illustration from [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview) does a good job:

[image]

So you would have to settle for either:

1. Set the thumbnail using `set_thumbnail` to have it shown on the right.
   I think it's an acceptable sacrifice and saves some space.
2. Use `set_image` and cram your information into the footer using `set_footer`.
   As can be noted, the footer ris shown in a smaller font and generally looks less good.